# Java Class inheriting self-referencial class

Tags: java, oop, generics, inheritance, tree

I'm trying to implement a simple Tree in a java class. However, I want another class to extend this Tree Class.

I'm making the tree recursive like this:

```
class Tree<T> {
    public T data;
    public List<Tree<T>> children;

    public Tree(T data){
        this.data = data;
    }
}
```

However, say I make a class like this:

```
class WeightedTree<T> extends Tree<T>
```

it's children are all regular trees, not Weighted Trees. Is there a way of accomplishing this with OOP principles?

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this:

```
class Tree<T, SELF extends Tree<T, SELF>> {
    public T data;
    public List<SELF> children;
}

class WeightedTree<T> extends Tree<T, WeightedTree<T>> {}
```

If you need to instantiate `Tree`, you can use a wildcard:

```
Tree<String, ?> tree = new Tree<>();
```

Or you can make an abstract base class with a self type and separate subclasses for `Tree` and `WeightedTree`.

Comment: Your wildcard example doesn't work: you can't instantiate such a type.

Comment: @ruakh You can though, if it's inferred.

Comment: My word, you're right! So bizarre. Thanks for the correction. :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
/* Package */ abstract class TreeBase<T, TREE_T extends TreeBase<T, TREE_T>> {
    public T data;
    public List<TREE_T> children;

    public TreeBase(T data) {
        this.data = data;
    }
}

public class Tree<T> extends TreeBase<T, Tree<T>> {
    public Tree(T data) {
        super(data);
    }
}

public class WeightedTree<T> extends TreeBase<T, WeightedTree<T>> {
    public WeightedTree(T data) {
        super(data);
    }
}
```